# Why does this regex result in four items?

Tags: python, regex, split

I want to split a string by , `->`, `=>`, or those wrapped with several spaces, meaning that I can get two items, `she` and `he`, from the following strings after being split:
`"she he", "she  he", "she he ", "she  he  ", "she->he", "she  ->he", "she=>he", "she=>  he", "  she->  he  ", "  she   =>  he \n"`

I have tried using this:

```
re.compile("(?<!^)((\\s*[-=]>\\s*)|[\\s+\t])(?!$\n)(?=[^\s])").split(' she  -> he \n')
```

What I get is a list with four items: `[' she', '  -> ', '  -> ', 'he \n']`.

And for this,

```
re.compile("(?<!^)((\\s*[-=]>\\s*)|[\\s+\t])(?!$\n)(?=[^\s])").split('she he')
```

I get this: `['she', ' ', None, 'he']`.

Why are there four items? And how can I get only two without the middle two?

Comment: `split` preserves the contents of your capture groups. Make them all non-capturing.

Comment: Can you not do a string.strip() before passing the string to the pattern.split? Makes it a little cleaner.

Comment: Try using `re.findall(...)`: `re.findall('\w+', " she  -> he \n")` will give `['she', 'he']`.

Comment: As per [documentation on re.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html): `If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.` @Rawing explained you the why thus. Your pattern is fairly complex, so unless you really need that much strict checks, approaches using simpler regex by pre-strip()-ing your line might be preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can just strip your input string. From your description, all you need is to split the words on either `\s+` or `\s*->\s*` or `\s*=>\s*`

So here is my solution:

```
p = re.compile(r'\s*[-=]>\s*|\s+')
input1 = "she he"
input2 = " she  -> he \n".strip()

print p.split(input1)
print p.split(input2)
```

Your output would be just 'she' and 'he':

```
['she', 'he']
```

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in comments already, each pair of parentheses in your regex forms a capture group, and each of those is returned by the regex `split()` function.  As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split),

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

Python regular expressions have a facility for non-capturing parentheses.  You use `(?:` instead of just `(` for the opening parenthesis to group without capturing.

```
>>> re.compile("(?<!^)((\\s*[-=]>\\s*)|[\\s+\t])(?!$\n)(?=[^\s])").split('she he')
['she', ' ', None, 'he']
>>> re.compile("(?<!^)(?:(?:\\s*[-=]>\\s*)|[\\s+\t])(?!$\n)(?=[^\s])").split('she he')
['she', 'he']
```

It's not exactly clear why you include a tab explicitly in the character class with `\s`; the `\s` already includes tab as one of the many whitespace characters it matches.

It's also not clear what you expect `$\n` to match.  `$` is the end of the line and `\n` is a literal newline character, so you seem to be trying to deal with newlines; but `$` alone already covers that.  The only difference between `$` and `$\n` is that if the end of the string (the last line in a multi-line string) is not newline-terminated, that will not match the latter.

The `(?<!^)` is also peculiar -- a better way to avoid matching an empty string is to make sure your regular expression always matches something.

From your requirements, it seems that

```
re.compile(r'\s*[-=]>\s*|\s+').split('he she')
```

would do what you want more succinctly and readably.  This matches an ASCII arrow (single- or double-stoke) with optional whitespace on both sides, or if that fails, falls back to a sequence of whitespace.

Comment: Good answer, Still leaves him with empty strings if used on the above example ' she  -> he \n'. I suggest using "filter()" on the result.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you are using parentheses "()" you are creating a capturing group. A capturing group is a part of a match. A match always refers to the complete regex string. That is why you are getting 4 results.

Documentation says: ["If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list."](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

You could try making the groups "non-capturing" as Rawing suggested. Do this by simply prepending "?:" inside the parentheses you do not want to be captured.

I would just leave out the parentheses altogether:

```
res = re.compile("\\s*[-=]>\\s*|\\s*").split(' she  -> he \n')
res = filter(None, res)
res = list(res)
```

Output:

```
['she', 'he']
```